# makefile with multiple folders

Tags: linux, macos, makefile

I have a question about makefiles, below is my project structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhzmU.png)
Below is my makefile

```
.PHONY:clean install distclean

INCLUDEPATH = ../include
LIBRARYPATH = ../lib 
LIBNAME =  ../lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib ../lib/libGL.dylib ../lib/libGLU.dylib

# third part libary
EXTERNALDIR = ../External
IMGUIDIR = ../External/Imgui/include
GLADDIR = ../External/glad/include
IMGUIZMODIR = ../External/Imguizmo
GLFWDIR = ../External/glfw

GLADSRC = ../External/glad/src
IMGUISRC = ../External/Imgui/src
IMGUIZMOSRC = ../External/Imguizmo


CC = gcc
C++ = g++ -std=c++17

C++FLAGS = -c -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -I$(EXTERNALDIR) -I$(IMGUIDIR)-I$(GLADDIR) -I$(IMGUIZMODIR) -I$(GLFWDIR)
CCFLAGS = -c -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -I$(GLADDIR)

LDFLAGS = -L$(LIBRARYPATH) $(LIBNAME)


TARGET = app
INSTALLPATH = /usr/bin/ 
RM = rm -rf
MV = sudo mv $(TARGET) $(INSTALLPATH)

CCFILES = $(wildcard *.c $(GLADSRC)/*.c)
C++FILES = $(wildcard *.cpp $(IMGUISRC)/*.cpp $(FILEDLGSRC)/*.cpp $(IMGUIZMOSRC)/*.cpp)

OBJFILES = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(CCFILES)) $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(C++FILES))


$(TARGET):$(OBJFILES)
    $(C++) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $<

%.o:%.cpp
    $(C++) $(C++FLAGS) $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
    $(RM) $(OBJFILES)
install:
    $(MV)
distclean:
    $(RM) $(INSTALLPATH) $(TARGET)
echo:
    -@echo $(SRCFILE)
    -@echo $(DESFILE)
removfile:
    -@rm clean
    -@rm clean_01
    -@rm clean_02
```

When I run the makefile, I will generate all the .o files in the src/ directory, which will cause the .o files to not be found in the subsequent compilation process and the compilation will fail. Any tips to fix it. For example, how do I put the .o files generated by .cpp in the external directory in the external directory instead of the src directory.

Comment: I'd add the targets and prerequisites explicitly to the makefile and try deriving patterns from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of changing the list of object files and the rules for building them:

```
OBJFILES = $(patsubst %.c,$(EXTERNALDIR)/%.o,$(CCFILES)) $(patsubst %.cpp,$(EXTERNALDIR)/%.o,$(C++FILES))

$(EXTERNALDIR)/%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(EXTERNALDIR)/%.o:%.cpp
    $(C++) $(C++FLAGS) $< -o $@
```